# Datasnapshot after mapping to object, object shows null values

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to fetch data from firebase database, i used valueEventListner 
Datasnapshot contains data, but when it is mapped to User object, object shows all atributes as null. Please suggest Solution

```
    mDatabaseReference =mFireBaseDatabase.getReference(table_name);
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v(TAG,"user snap shot count:"+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            // users is arraylist
        users.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot usersnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Profile user snap:"+usersnapshot.toString());

                   User user = usersnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    Log.v(TAG,"user data:"+user.toString());
                }

        }
```

Comment: post your user class structure and your firebase db structure

Comment: Please add your model class and your database structure.

Comment: i got solve my issue, i had missed the child() .   thank you

Answer (score 0):

when you insert data that time pass user object like below ..

```
        User user = new User(name, email, pwd);
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(name).setValue(user);
```

then your code ok i think when you read data that time define firebase instance ..

```
        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  mDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");
```